# Assuming I have a C# code that creates a group of WPF controls. Can I replace it with a piece of XAML + an Instantiation call?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls

I thought maybe Control Templates, Data Templates, Styles - but they all seem to be for different things. I'm interested in this so I could use Blend to design the Group of controls.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and bind its `ItemsSource` to a collection of objects which contain the data you want to show in the controls. You then need to set the `ItemsControl`'s `ItemTemplate` to actually show the controls.

Check out this [WPF ItemsControl Example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example)

Comment: That's not what I have in mind. A "sort of" solution would be to have a dummy window for my Groups so I can edit them in Blend. Then, when I Need to copy a Group to a window I want to Display, I can do what is done at the bottom of this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx . The Problem with that is, I don't get references to the controls I create, so it's complicated to do anything with them, like adding click handlers etc.

Comment: Besides, it might not be efficient to do XAML parsing at runtime.

Comment: It sounds like you have completely misunderstood WPF and are trying to use it like WinForms ;) Can you please tell me why you can't add click handlers in ItemTemplates?

Comment: Hmm, might be. I know there is this: http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html but how can you define a DataTemplate without writing it by hand in xaml - after all I could write it by Hand in c# as well and that's what I don't want to do. Besides that, there is this template selector which again is written in C#. So xaml can't switch between different templates depending on some properties of the data by itself. Also, if I do something like that, it's hard to tell when exactly what happens.

Comment: It's like filling out a lot of gaps and afterwards it works somehow, but you never know what happens exactly when and in what order and how. Or at least, I have never found documentation about this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should never really need to create WPF controls in code. Except maybe windows and dialogs. 
Now i don't understand your question but as khellang already pointed out, an ItemsControl is a very easy way to show a list of something. This can be anything thanks to WPFs very flexible way of showing content. `DataTemplate`s play a big part in it, because it more or less tells WPF "I have an object XYZ and i want WPF to display it like this". `ControlTemplate`s are similar but are not about your data, instead they define how a control should look, you want a button which only is a colorized rect? ControlTemplate is the way to go.
Styles in a nutshell are predefined macros to set properties on a WPF Control.

Now what you ask, or better what i understood, is best accomplished with a `ContentControl` and `DataTemplate`. Just place the ContentControl where you want your group of controls to be placed, and use a DataTemplate assigned to the ContentControls `ContentTemplate` property to define the group of controls.